# REGEX for accented characters

Tags: php, regex

I need to build a regex (in PHP) that match if a string has at least one character different from a set provided. Here is my set:

A to Z and a to z, numbers, and áéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ¡¿!?-:

So this word should not match: Sebastián
This match: Sebastiàn

I reprhased the question due to the comment of varchar256. BTW, when examples differ from verbose instructions, take the example as the true intention of the author of the doc.

Comment: What is the reason to allow certain accented chars and not others? That might make things simpler, with for instance locale use.

Comment: You say the string cannot match if it matches one of the set you mentioned, and that set included unaccented letters. Yet you gave 'Sebastiàn' as an example. That's a bit confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9áéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ¡¿!?\-:]/', ...);
```

Note the `^` inside the brackets - that inverts the match, so this regex will match on any strings which contains at least one character that is NOT listed inside the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Use a character set pattern: `preg_match('/[^\wáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ¡¿!?-:]/')`

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "Sebastiàn";

$clean_string = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-ZáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ¡¿!?\\-:]*/",$string);
```

make sure to escape the dash in character class.